# In C++ how to pass uint16_t variable to the function with an argument unsigned int &?

Tags: c++

I have a variable `uint16_t a=35;` and I have a function

```
UINT Read(unsigned int& nVal);
```

How do I pass `a` to `Read()` as `unsigned int&`?

If I pass like this

```
Read(a);
```

I am getting the error below:

> cannot convert parameter 1 from 'uint16_t' to 'unsigned int &

Comment: *I have variable uint16_t a=35;* Therein lies your problem and solution.

Answer (score 6):

You will need to copy the value into a (named) temporary, call the function, and then copy the temp back (possibly after checking for overflow).

```
uint16_t a = 35;
...
unsigned int temp = a;
const unsigned int result = Read(temp);
// check for overflow here
a = temp;
```

Of course, if you can change the definition of `a` to be `unsigned int`, then that is much more straightforward (but I assume that is not possible for other reasons).

Answer (score 3):

Since `Read` takes a reference to a non-const `unsigned int`, you cannot pass it a temporary. You must create an actual `unsigned int` somewhere to bind to this reference:

```
unsigned int au16 = a;
Read(au16);
a = au16; // don't forget to impact on a the changes made on au16
```

Answer (score 3):

The other answers all give a solution, but I thought I'd delve a bit deeper in *why* you see the error in the first place.

What's happening is, **for your compiler** `uint16_t` and `unsigned int` are different types (it most probably implements `unsigned int`s with 32 bits) and `uint16_t` is convertible into `unsigned int`, so there is an implicit cast hidden in the function call.

This cast generates a *temporary*, that is, a nameless entity that is then passed down to the function as parameter.
Since the function takes a *non-const* reference, there is the possibility that the function will modify the referenced variable. Since the referenced variable is *not* `a`, but the temporary, any change happening to it would be (invisibly) lost.

To prevent this, C++ forbids you to pass temporaries (or, more correctly, *`rvalue`s*, of which `temporary` is just one type) as non-const references.

Please note that, for `const` references, the problem of accidentally losing modifications doesn't exist, because you can't modify the referenced value. Thus, C++ doesn't forbid you passing `rvalue`s there.

Comment: "uint16_t and unsigned int are different types" -> not necessarily.

Comment: @Bathsheba better?